# Error Overload when updating Web app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> Error 2   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be
>   called without a narrowing conversion:     'Public Sub New(name As
>   String, type As System.TypeCode, defaultValue As String)': Argument
>   matching parameter 'defaultValue' narrows from 'Integer' to 'String'. 
>   'Public Sub New(name As String, dbType As System.Data.DbType,
>   defaultValue As String)': Argument matching parameter 'dbType' narrows
>   from 'System.TypeCode' to 'System.Data.DbType'.     'Public Sub
>   New(name As String, dbType As System.Data.DbType, defaultValue As
>   String)': Argument matching parameter 'defaultValue' narrows from
>   'Integer' to 'String'.    E:\PC\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\TIVENCA\Fuente\Tivenca
>   10-12-2008\Mega.TimeCard.Web\Cargar\CargarCopy.aspx.vb    1365

Hi, i just updatetd an old vb .net web app and when i rebuild it shows me that error, here is the code

```
Dim Parameter As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter("idproyecto", TypeCode.Int32, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Dim Parameter As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter("idproyecto", TypeCode.Int32, "0")
```

It expexts "defaultValue" to be of String type.